# Can disclosed sins be forgiven?

Tags: islamic-basis

If someone commit shirk and hebecome frightened and shared with some pious person if it is forgivable or not and want to know how to fix it. They don't brag or damn care about it but they want to know solution. Plus if that person shared with family through he was terrified and depressed. Will Allah forgive such person or any hadith applied to him?